# cant use the variable that i send to a blade component page

Tags: php, laravel

hi sorry for my bad engilsh.

im using blade component page in laravel to include a blade page in another blade page
i use component blade page.
i send A VARIABLE that its name is "post" like this

```
  @foreach($posts->skip(1) as $post)
            <x-post-card :post="$post"/>
            @endforeach
```

i use `@props(['post'])` on that page to get the variable
`@props(['post'])`
and when put 'post'
on @ddd its fine and  ok
[image: dd the $post variable]

but when i wonna use its property like 'title' the laravel send me a error that Undefined variable: post

[image: use the property of post]

this the way i use property

```
@props(['post'])
@dd($post)
<article class="transition-colors duration-300 hover:bg-gray-100 border border-black border-opacity-0 hover:border-opacity-5 rounded-xl">
    <div class="py-6 px-5 lg:flex">
        <div class="flex-1 lg:mr-8">
            <img src="/images/illustration-1.png" alt="Blog Post illustration" class="rounded-xl">
        </div>

        <div class="flex-1  flex flex-col justify-between">
            <header class="mt-8 lg:mt-0">
                <div class="space-x-2">
                    <a href="/categories/{{$post->category->slug }}" class="px-3 py-1 border border-blue-300 rounded-full text-blue-300 text-xs uppercase font-semibold" style="font-size: 10px">{{$post->category->name}}</a>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-4">
                    <h1  class="text-3xl .bold">
                        {{$post->title}}
                    </h1>

                    <span class="mt-2 block text-gray-400 text-xs">
                                        Published <time>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</time>
                                    </span>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="text-sm mt-2">
                <p>
                  {{$post->excerpt}}
                </p>
            </div>

            <footer class="flex justify-between items-center mt-8">
                <div class="flex items-center text-sm">
                    <img src="/images/lary-avatar.svg" alt="Lary avatar">
                    <div class="ml-3">
                       <a href="/authors/{{$post->user->username}}"><h5 class="font-bold">{{$post->user->name}}</h5></a>
                        <h6>Mascot at Laracasts</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="hidden lg:block">
                    <a href="#" class="transition-colors duration-300 text-xs font-semibold bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded-full py-2 px-8">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Can we see how you defined the relationship

Comment: Maybe it shows `@dd` successfully for the first post, but then the error happens on some OTHER post in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

look at the ddd Error
maybe you have some  with instead 
and the varaible is undefined on that.

```
<x-slot name="content">

    @include('_posts-header');

    <main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-6 lg:mt-20 space-y-6">

        <x-post-feature-card :post="$posts[0]"/>

        <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2">
            
            @foreach ($posts->skip(1) as $post )

                <x-post-card :post="$post"/>

            @endforeach

        </div>

        <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3">
```

/*erase that or pass parameter*/

```
            <x-post-card />
            <x-post-card />
            <x-post-card />
```

/**/

```
        </div>
    </main>
</x-slot>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).